# Increasing and wide spreading cost function with Stochastic Gradient Descent

Tags: tensorflow, gradient-descent

I am using Tensorflow in an online learning environment.
As cost function is implemented:

```
cost = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.sub(Y, output))))
```

Optimization is done like:

```
train_op = tf.train
            .GradientDescentOptimizer(0.0001)
            .minimize(cost,name="GradientDescent")
```

And I run Stochastic Gradient Descent like:

```
m, i = sess.run([merged, train_op], feed_dict={X: input_batch,Y:label_batch})
```

Whereby input_batch and label_batch contain only one vector each.

So how can I interpret a cost function like:
[image]

Is this a good progress for a stochastic approach?
Why the gap gets bigger?

I train the network 50'000 times with the same 50 training examples.
So each example is used for training 10'000 times every 51th step.

I tried already to change the learning rate by factor 10 in both ways.
This question is related to my other question from: [Does Stochastic Gradient Descent even work with TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41224983/does-stochastic-gradient-descent-even-work-with-tensorflow)

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Which one is the error you tell about?

Comment: The violet one, ignore the other please.

Comment: I had to correct:
I train the network 50'000 times with the same 50 training examples.
So each example is used for training 10'000 times every 51th step.